# Multiples base de datos db2 Consulta con DBEAVER

Tags: sql, db2

me he instalado en el trabajo Dbeaver y la verdad que me gusta un montón pero no se si tiene una funcionalidad que me gustaría hacer......no la encuentro.

En el trabajo tengo como mas de 100 base de datos db2, correspondientes cada una a un centro diferente, tiene todo igual con sus directorios y ficheros iguales y lo único que cambia son los datos.

Tengo una sql para consultar datos y la tengo que lanzar una a una en cada base de datos para traerme los datos.
Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma con el dbeaver de que lance la misma consulta conectandose a las diferentes base de datos y me recopile los resultados el solito

Gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puede crear una tarea en DBeaver que luego se puede ejecutar en múltiples bases de datos https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Task-Management/

Comment: Hola Paul, voy a investigar. Muchas Gracias